# Should I use "told you" or "have told you" in this example?

Tags: verbs

Sentence:

> She obviously has a legit excuse, although she could have been more responsible and told you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

> She obviously has a legit excuse, although she could have been more responsible and "have" told you in advance.

You need to use "could" again if you are using "have" again.

> She obviously has a legit excuse, although she could have been more responsible and could have told you in advance.

That makes it redundant. Therefore, stick to the first option which is:

> She obviously has a legit excuse, although she could have been more responsible and told you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The first *have* covers both *been more responsible* and *told you* in that sentence. So as it stands, it is fine.

Comment: @Robusto: Isn't it like if one verb is an action verb ('told') and the other one is a copula verb ('been') then the previous auxiliary verb/verbs, if there is/are such, should be present in both cases ('...she COULD HAVE been more responsible and COULD HAVE told you in advance')?

Comment: *Have* can be a helper verb for copula or any other verb.

Comment: @brilliant: That's not a rule I've ever come across. I'm sure there are situations where repeating the auxiliaries will be clearer, but I don't think it's ever strictly necessary if they're identical. Certainly in this case it sounds much better without the repetition because the link between the two verbs is very close (ie the implication is that "be responsible" and "tell you" are the same thing; that implication would be lost by repeating the "could have"...)

Comment: @Robusto: "Have can be a helper verb for copula or any other verb" - I don't understand what you want to say by it. Sure, the verb 'have' can be a helper verb for copula or any other verb, but how is this related to my question?

Comment: @psmears: (1) "That's not a rule I've ever come across" - I read it in some English grammar book, but I don't remember which one.  "...that implication would be lost by repeating the "could have" - Why do you think this implication would be lost? To me  "she could have been more responsible and told you" sounds like the was another pronoun between "and" and "told", except either the speaker didn't say loud enough or I didn't hear it clearly. For example, "she could have been more responsible and <WE> told you". Whereas the repetition of "COULD HAVE" makes

Comment: (2) it more obvious that both verbs belong to the same subject 'she'.

Comment: @brilliant: It's possible that "some English grammar book" is wrong, or at least that it's stating a good guideline as a rule (it wouldn't be the first time that either of those thappened :-). The implication would be lost because the "could have been XXX and done YYY" is a common idiom with that meaning (other variations with other verb combinations also work eg "could have helped and shown you ZZZ"), and putting in the redundant auxiliary verbs makes it sound like you're deliberately separating them to avoid that implication.

Comment: @psmears: (1) As far as the book is concerned, I am not sure, but I usually read grammar books published by some universities. I just asked, I don't insist on that rule.

Comment: @psmears: (2) the "could have been XXX and done YYY" is a common idiom with that meaning (other variations with other verb combination also work eg "could have helped and shown you ZZZ")" - Allow me to challenge this statement of yours. The thing is in both of your examples the second verbs “done” and “shown” can’t be confused with their Past Simple forms: (have) done – did, (have) shown – showed; but in the example that we have in this question the second verb “told” has the same form in Perfect Tenses and in the Past Simple Tense: (have) told – told. Therefore, it can easily be taken for a

Comment: @psmears: (3) predicate of a new clause, which is now in the Past Simple, and the subject of which was either misheard by the listener, or, perhaps, omitted by the speaker (in my example this subject is “we”). Plus, in the example in this question we also have the word “more” (“…although she could have been MORE responsible and told you…”), which modifies only the

Comment: @psmears: (4) first verbal phrase (“been responsible”), but not the second one (“told you in advance”) – it is obvious that the speaker means a higher degree of “being responsible”, and not the higher degree of “telling in advance” (which can even hardly be imagined). So, this modifier “more” in this sentence makes these two verbs (“been” and “told”) even more different from each other and less likely to belong to the same subject (“she”).

Comment: @brilliant: @(1) I am sure you have good grammar books, since you write well, but it is a sad fact that there are many books that give "rules" of English grammar that are at best guidelines, and at worst simply wrong. So do take care :)

Comment: @brilliant @(2-4) I understand the point you're making, but the idiom works even with regular verbs and others where the past participle & simple past are identical ("she could have been Xxx and handed you her notice/helped you out/hit him"). To a native speaker it is much more natural to assume the verbs have the same subject than to try to insert a new subject that's not there (and that would make the meaning very strange). Even in your "more" example, the "more" only modifies "responsible", so there is no need for or even suggestion of a different subject...

Comment: @psmears:  (1) “To a native speaker it is much more natural to assume the verbs have the same subject than to try to insert a new subject” – Sure, I can’t argue here since I am not a native English speaker, so I can’t tell which things are more natural to native speakers and which things are not. It may be so that a phrase is grammatically correct, but to a native speaker it would sound kind of unusual.

Comment: @psmears: (2) I think it has to do with how many times you have heard a phrase/pattern and used it in your daily conversations. And, of course, any native speaker heard various things spoken in English way more often than even a best non-native learner of English of the same age. This case is quite a surprise for me, though, because my non-native mind almost “screams” to me that “she could have been more responsible and told you in advance” sounds unusual and rather awkward. I am really surprised and a bit perplexed.

Comment: @brilliant: I feel your pain here - I am currently learning another language (Arabic) and seem to get that feeling of surprise and confusion on a daily basis :)